# Zabbix trigger last N text values matches regexp

Tags: zabbix

I check if error occurred by checking whether the last value matches regexp.

```
({myhost.com:my.item.regexp(^ERROR$)})#0
```

I need some tolerance by checking not last but last N values to match the regexp, i.e. last 2-3 values.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Zabbix function documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions), function regexp() accepts a second parameter - the number of seconds or values to analyze. Unfortunately, it will return 1 if at least one of the values matches, which is not what you need - you need all values to match.

Therefore, if your regular expression is simple enough, consider using count() function with "eq" or "like" operators:

```
{host:item.count(#3,ERROR,eq)} = 3
{host:item.count(#3,ERROR,like)} = 3
```

There is also a feature request to be able to use regular expressions in count() function and it is tracked at [ZBXNEXT-1250](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1250).

Comment: Since [Zabbix 3.2](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) using `regexp` is possible, for example: `{myhost.com:my.item.count(#3,"^ERROR$","regexp")} = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like

```
({myhost.com:my.item.regexp(^ERROR$).max(#3)}=0)
```

work for you? If not, just use the built-in trigger expression constructor in Zabbix web GUI, it makes this kind of stuff easier, if not easy.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion tries to use two functions on an item, whereas Zabbix supports only one.